# Manually insert ObjectId with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I got an object called "article" that I directly iinsert nto MongoDB. But I'm having issue with one of the sub-objects:

```
article.tags = ObjectId("' + tags + '");
//This doesn't work because: ObjectId is not defined
article.tags = "ObjectId("' + tags + '")"; 
//This works half-way because: ObjectId gets inserted as a custom value "ObjectId"
// inside commas, not as a true
// ObjectId, therefore my application won't interpret it.
```

I have thought of requiring some mongodb driver in the app, would it work? Is there any cleaner way to approach this?

Note: Tags are already defined and properly indexed in the database, and they must be inserted this way.

Comment: I think you can just assign the string value of the ObjectId and it'll turn it in to a proper id. Such as `article.tags = "553ecd7c0942f211d4420b36"`

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve, are you trying to set a single ObjectId as reference for a document's property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Maybe it's just a typo: ObjectI**d** !== ObjectI**D** ???

---

Have you required ObjectID or only mongodb client?

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

then you should do:

```
var someId = new ObjectID("ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF") // should be 24 byte long
```

Comment: Thanks!! var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId; !